# How to Versionize Ansible (Tower) with GitHUB

Tags: ansible, github

I have configured Ansible Tower with Centos 7.2 and I am able to see my Tower dashboard.  My major concern is how to do versioninzation in Ansible Tower as given in [this link](https://www.ansible.com/configuration-management) with Github.

Since I have written the playbook for configuration changes in my Centos server and push my changes to GITHUB in a branch as `SAAS_1` now that I have to integrate this changes to Ansible Tower, how can I see this versioning? How can I visually see all of this content in Ansible Tower?

Like production -1.1 UFT-2.1 and continuation based on changes enabled

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

one strategy is to put your playbook repo(s) thru a regular build/deploy pipeline, where you separate between "nonrelease" and "release", for example by linking the master branch to "release" (most CI tools support this out of the box). Then you'd have two "streams" of artifacts you could deploy, one for release and one for non-release (or release candidate or whatever you'd like to call it). These can be auto-deployed to different folders inside Ansible tower and then picked up as different "projects". That way youd have two "instances" of every playbook folder (or "project" as Tower calls them).